# Replacing java class?

Tags: java, class, classloader, antivirus

I'm working on a sandbox feature for my java antivirus, and I've come into a question: Does the specified package on a class matter for compilation?

Example:
I'm running a program that wants to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()`, when the classloader attempts to load that to run a method, does it check the package qualified in the file, if they exist? I would prefer not to try and change files in the JVM, but to simply load ones from a different package. I can accomplish the loading and such, but my only dilemma, will it crash and burn? Inside the java, it would be registered as say, `java.lang.Runtime`, but the compiled code will say for example `pkg.pkg.Runtime` and will it need to extend the old runtime? My guess is that extending the old runtime would just break it. Does anyone know anything about this? I'm working on making a testable example, but I'm still a bit away and wanted to get some answers, as well as this might benefit some people.

Comment: A class is referenced with its full package name. `java.lang.Runtime`, boom, that's it.

Comment: Some code snippets would help with understanding what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the specified package on a class matter for compilation?

Yes it does matter.  A class called `pkg.pkg.Runtime()` cannot be loaded *as if* it was `java.lang.Runtime`.

Furthermore, if my memory is correct, the JVM has some additional security measures in it to prevent normal applications from injecting classes into core packages such as `java.lang`.

If you need to change the behaviour of the `java.lang.Runtime` class (for experimental purposes!) then I think you will need to put your modified version on the *boot classpath*, ahead of the "rt.jar" file.

However:

- This level of tinkering can easily result in JVM instability; i.e. hard JVM crashes that are difficult to diagnose.
- If your aim is to produce a "production quality" tool, then you will find that things that involve tinkering with the JVM are not considered acceptable.  People are going to be very suspicious of installation instructions that say things like "add this to your installed JVM's bootclasspath".
- Distributing a "tinkered with" JVM may fall foul of Oracle's Java licensing agreement.

---

My advice would be to look for a less intrusive way of doing what you are trying to do.  For instance, if you are trying to do virus checking, either do it outside of the JVM, or in a custom application classloader.

---

You commented:

> I have a custom classloader, my question is: If I compile a class that is labelled as say, pkg.pkg.Runtime, can I register in my classloader as java.lang.Runtime?

As I said above, no you can't.  A bytecode file has the classname embedded in it.  If you attempt to "pull a swifty" by loading a class with a different name, the JVM will throw an `Error`.

And:

> If not, then how can I replace the class? If the compiled package name has to equal the request referenced naming, then can I modify the .class file to to match, or perhaps compile it as if it were in the java.lang package?

That's what you would have to do.  You need to *name* the class `java.lang.Runtime` in the source code and compile it as such.

But what I *meant* by my advice above is that you should use do the virus checking in the class loader.  *Forget about* trying to replace / modify the behaviour of `Runtime`.  It is a bad idea for the reasons I listed above.

Comment: I have a custom classloader, my question is: If I compile a class that is labeled as say, `pkg.pkg.Runtime`, can I register in my classloader as `java.lang.Runtime`? If not, then how can I replace the class? If the compiled package name has to equal the request referenced naming, then can I modify the .class file to to match, or perhaps compile it as if it were in the java.lang package?